# Writing equations in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mathematics

How can we write something like 10-10 (1 0 bar1 0) in Photoshop?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to type maths formulas directly into Photoshop, unless there's some plugin I'm not aware of.

Instead, enter your formula in MS Word or LibreOffice Text, or if you're more familiar with LaTeX use that, then export as PDF.

Then open the PDF in Photoshop at the desired size, and from there copy and paste it into your Photoshop document.

Here's an example using a PDF created in LibreOffice Text using *Insert > Object > Formula*, saved as a PDF and opened in Photoshop

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is how I have been doing so far. Its a lot of work and was looking for an easier way.

Comment: For your specific example, it would be possible to type 1010, then just draw the overbar above the number 1.  But obviously this approach isn't so usable with more complex formulas where the PDF method is by far the most efficient.

Comment: @Vivek you could automate this but how often do you use this kind of feature (see this [this table](https://xkcd.com/1205/))

Answer (score 0):

- I usually use a [Computer Modern font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) to write math in Photoshop. As Billy Kerr comments, you could just draw a bar above the 1.
- Generating a pdf and then importing it into Photoshop works well, but is a bit long.
- You can also use a website like [latex2png](http://latex2png.com) to generate equations.